# Does each partition of a date partitioned table in Google Big Query have its own cache?

Tags: caching, google-bigquery, database-partitioning

A customer of mine is using Google BigQuery, but he is a little worried about the costs involved. After closer inspection, the many inserts queries were often incurring high costs because the cache was constantly being invalidated. I recommended using a date partitioned table for this. This will make sure queries only run against distinct parts of the table, reducing the costs.

But my customer does actually often run against old partitions, but these are rarely updated. It would make sense if each partition would also maintain their own cache but I have been unable to find any official documentation stating this. As I want to give the customer an estimate of the new cost projection, it would be nice if I can confirm separate caches are maintained for each partition.

Comment: Could you share an approximate cost that you have reached and want to cut.

Comment: You could manually fetch the results in a temp table, and set an expiration time on it, so automatically will cleanup.

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanks for the alternative, this or doing manual partitioning seems the way to go for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. At this point we don't support caching per partition. I have logged an internal feature request for this.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying, hope it will be a feature soon!

Comment: @Pavan, not supporting caching probably also does not work when use a date partitoned table PLUS streaming inserts?Caching of the static partitions as new streaming data is coming in would be really useful

Comment: We use BQ as analytics backend for streaming data in the public transport domain. 
We have many large tables with date-partitioning enabled, and streaming inserts occur typically only on the last partition. Having the query caching automatically exploiting this fact, would mean we could concentrate more on business logic 
instead of also having to think about costs and build clumsy workarounds 
such as application-side caching and materialized views. If you too support this feature plase upvote the corresponding feature request, here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109634903